# Raspberry PI OS on SSD "goes to sleep while running"

Tags: ssd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I just bought a SSD and an Adapter for my pi to run the system on them. After some small complications with getting the backup image from the SD-Card to the SSD and everything seems to be fine. I got a big command input lag (the command output took 10-20s to happen when using htop or top or anything else) at the first start, but was gone after some minutes. But after some time 1-2 hours my pi didn't response anymore. After a restart it happens the same again. So i pluged it in my pc and there seems to be a disconnect from the SSD after some time to.

Could it be that the SSD goes into sleep mode? Or something like that? I pluged a display in to my pi, to see what happens and i saw that the system doesnt respond anymore (touch and keyboard) and the ssh connection doesnt recognizes any command anymore:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.92-v8+ #1514 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 17 17:39:38 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
*TIMEGAP like 5-10 Minutes*
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -i
-bash: sudo: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -i
-bash: sudo: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-get install sudo
-bash: apt-get: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ htop
-bash: htop: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano
-bash: nano: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ reboot
-bash: reboot: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ awd <-- just spam
-bash: awd: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dw <-- just spam
-bash: dw: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dwa <-- just spam
-bash: dwa: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dw <-- just spam
-bash: dw: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname
-bash: /usr/bin/uname: Input/output error
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
-bash: /usr/bin/uname: Input/output error
```

Later i happens after i logged myself into the root user after sudo -i

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo -i

Wi-Fi is currently blocked by rfkill.
Use raspi-config to set the country before use.

root@raspberrypi:~# sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/nano: Input/output error
root@raspberrypi:~# awd
-bash: awd: command not found
root@raspberrypi:~# top
-bash: top: command not found
```

SSD: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07G3KGYZQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G3KGYZQ) Adapter: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00N4JLNXM/

OS: Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) with Desktop (Latest, from 28.01.2022) (I used the Raspberry Pi Imager 1.7.1 to flash my SSD)

Does anybody know where or what the problem is?

And sry for my bad english ;)

Comment: It might help you to have a look into the syslog while the issue occurs. You can use `journalctl -f` for that in a different tty. Sidenote: Depending on how you've put the image from the SD to the SSD it might be necessary to update the information in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: These things happens even with the fresh install. My thought is that the harddrive just disconnects. I will look into it tomorrow. Ty for the help. @mashuptwice